# How to Enable Drop Commit in WebStorm's Git Local Unprotected Branch

Tags: git, intellij-idea, webstorm

How can I forcefully enable `Drop Commit` for any commit in my local unprotected branch (local unprotected branch which is NOT tracking any remote branch) ?

Currently `Drop Commit` is disabled for already published commits coming from master branch, as this local branch branches OFF master.

Otherwise I have to do hard reset and cherry pick commits.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you branch is listed as "Protected" branch under File | Settings | Version Control | Git

If you remove a branch from that list, then `Drop commit` action should become available